# How do I sync a Product's Online Date, but not the Variant's Online Date?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How do I sync a Product's Online Date, but not the Variant's Online Date? I have a MyProduct, which is a subclass of Product. I also have a MyVariant, which is a concrete subclass of VariantProduct.

NOTE: onlineDate is an OOTB attribute of Product

I am looking to do something like this:

```
INSERT_UPDATE SyncAttributeDescriptorConfig;syncJob(code)[unique=true][path-delimiter=!];attributeDescriptor(enclosingType(code), qualifier)[unique=true];includedInSync;copyByValue
# Sync Product's Online Date
;MySyncJob;MyProduct:onlineDate;true;true
# DO NOT sync variant's Online Date
;MySyncJob;MyVariant:onlineDate;false;false
```

Unfortunately, I get a warning like this:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/08/21 19:43:29.731 | [m[1;33m0821_19:43:29,647 WARN  [ImpExResultProcessWorker] (00000000-ImpEx-Import)  [de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.ImpExImportReader.dumpUnresolvedLine:811] line 3 at main script: dumped unresolved line ValueLine[unresolvable:line 3: cannot create SyncAttributeDescriptorConfig with values ItemAttributeMap[ registry:  null, type: <null>, data: {syncjob=MySyncJob(8796095414772), copybyvalue=true, includedinsync=true, attributedescriptor=MyProduct.onlineDate:java.util.Date[/rwoSRp]} ] due to [de.hybris.platform.catalog.impl.SyncAttributeDescriptorConfigValidator@139e7948]:Attribute AttributeDescriptorModel (8796237725783) is inherited - use the declared one.,line 3 at main script,null,HeaderDescriptor[line 2 at main script, insert_update, SyncAttributeDescriptorConfig, {}, [syncJob, attributeDescriptor, includedInSync, copyByValue] ],{1=ValueEntry('MySyncJob'=MySyncJob(8796095414772),unresolved=false,ignore=false), 2=ValueEntry('MyProduct:onlineDate'=MyProduct.onlineDate:java.util.Date[/rwoSRp],unresolved=false,ignore=false), 3=ValueEntry('true'=true,unresolved=false,ignore=false), 4=ValueEntry('true'=true,unresolved=false,ignore=false)}]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/08/21 19:43:29.731 | [m[1;33m0821_19:43:29,647 WARN  [ImpExResultProcessWorker] (00000000-ImpEx-Import)  [de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.ImpExImportReader.dumpUnresolvedLine:811] line 4 at main script: dumped unresolved line ValueLine[unresolvable:line 4: cannot create SyncAttributeDescriptorConfig with values ItemAttributeMap[ registry:  null, type: <null>, data: {syncjob=MySyncJob(8796095414772), copybyvalue=false, includedinsync=false, attributedescriptor=MyVariant.onlineDate:java.util.Date[/rwoSRp]} ] due to [de.hybris.platform.catalog.impl.SyncAttributeDescriptorConfigValidator@139e7948]:Attribute AttributeDescriptorModel (8796267872343) is inherited - use the declared one.,line 4 at main script,null,HeaderDescriptor[line 2 at main script, insert_update, SyncAttributeDescriptorConfig, {}, [syncJob, attributeDescriptor, includedInSync, copyByValue] ],{1=ValueEntry('MySyncJob'=MySyncJob(8796095414772),unresolved=false,ignore=false), 2=ValueEntry('MyVariant:onlineDate'=MyVariant.onlineDate:java.util.Date[/rwoSRp],unresolved=false,ignore=false), 3=ValueEntry('false'=false,unresolved=false,ignore=false), 4=ValueEntry('false'=false,unresolved=false,ignore=false)}]
```

Is what I want even possible with Hybris OOTB?

Comment: The validator error message "Attribute AttributeDescriptorModel (8796237725783) is inherited - use the declared one." of the SyncAttributeDescriptorConfigValidator sounds like hybris explicitly disallows what you are trying to do. Obviously they only allow to edit the attribute on the type it is declared for and none of its subtypes.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JohannesNolte I understand what the error is trying to say. What I want is for MyProduct's online date to be synced, and MyVariant's online date NOT to be synced. I thought configuring SyncAttributeDescriptorConfig would work, but it just causes an error / warning. So from my understanding, it's all or nothing. The online date of both the Products and the Variants will be synced or not. It can't be just the Product's online date or the Variant's online date. Do I make sense?

Comment: I think you are right. What I don't get is why you are trying to do that. Maybe there is a different approach to solve your problem.

Comment: @JohannesNolte Business requirements, unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe you can add custom field for this. We generally adding firstOnlineDate to product.

Comment: @mkysoft Thanks! I'm thinking of doing that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change this accordingly and try:

```
$syncJobCode = sync xxxProductCatalog\:Staged->xxxProductCatalog\:Online
INSERT_UPDATE SyncAttributeDescriptorConfig; attributeDescriptor(enclosingType(code), qualifier)[unique = true]; includedInSync; syncJob(code)[unique = true]; copyByValue
                                           ; Product:onlineDate                                                ; false         ; $syncJobCode                ; false
                                           ; GenericVariantProduct:onlineDate                                  ; false         ; $syncJobCode                ; false
```